# How to restart a javafx application?

Tags: java, javafx

Here is the code for restarting the JavaFX app without fxml.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class HelloFX extends Application
{
boolean state = true;

@Override
public void start( final Stage primaryStage )
{
    System.out.println( "state is " + state );
    playGame();
    System.out.println( "state is " + state );

    final Button restartButton = new Button( "Restart" );
    restartButton.setOnAction( __ ->
    {
        System.out.println( "Restarting app!" );
        primaryStage.close();
        Platform.runLater( () -> new HelloFX().start( new Stage() ) );
    } );
    primaryStage.setScene( new Scene( new StackPane( restartButton ) ) );
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * Simulate a game play by changing the global state.
 */
private void playGame()
{
    state = false;
}

/**
 * @param args ignored.
 */
public static void main( final String[] args )
{
    launch( args );
}
}
```

But, I want to do this with fxml.

I didn't know how to apply this code with fxml.

My code.

Main.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Controller.java

```
package sample;

public class Controller {

}
```

sample.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
<children>
  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#restart" text="restart" />
</children>
</GridPane>
```

I want to restart my JavaFX application.

I didn't know how to apply this code with fxml.

How can I restart my JavaFX application with fxml ?

Comment: the non-fxml version already looks fishy (generally you shouldn't call start directly, you might get away with it in this case because application is already fired up .. wouldn't bet on it functioning reliably, though) - why do you want to re-start? Instead, simply replace the game field (at most the root of the scene). With that, do some research on how to change scene's content in fxml (just reload :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```java
public void restartApplication()
{
  final File currentFile = new File(TheCurrentClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());

  /* is it a jar file? */
  if(!currentJar.getName().endsWith(".jar"))
    return;

  /* Build command: java -jar application.jar */
  final String command = "java -jar " + currentJar.getPath();

  final ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
  builder.start();
  System.exit(0);
}
```

This basically restarts the program via the `java -jar` command